# Convert Sql Query to Named Query

Tags: java, sql, jpa

```
SELECT col1 || col2 FROM TABLE
WHERE col3= '3' and substr(col4, 1,2) = 'I1'
```

I am trying to convert this SQL query to named query. I am trying to get col1 and col2 using query and concatenate them at the end, but facing a problem with substring part. I am not sure how to include it in my named query.

Sample Data in the table -

**col1 | col2 | col3 | col4**

3    | I21  | Hi   | how
3    | I22  | are  | you
3    | I23  | mr   | xx
3    | I 2  | Hi   | how
3    | K31  | Hi   | how
3    | K32  | are  | you
3    | J 1  | Hi   | how

```
@NamedQuery(name = "retrieveMessage", query = "SELECT i.col1, i.col2 FROM TABLE i where i.col3= :col3 AND substr(i.col4,1,2) = :col4")
```

Comment: errm, using JPQL SUBSTRING and CONCAT perhaps? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL has the [SUBSTRING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html#ejb3_overview_query_functions) function:

```
SUBSTRING(col4, 1,2) = :col4
```

Comment: I tried substring in place of substr and it worked. Thank you